# javascript/backbone js passing parameters to functions - some doubts

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, function-parameter

This may be a javascript 101 or Backbone 100 questions.  But I feel comfortable in asking this beginning question and not being made fun of here :)

The following code snippet is from Code School's Anatomy of Backbone JS course:

```
render: function(){ 
    this.collection.forEach(this.addOne, this);
} 

addOne: function(todoItem){
    var todoView = new TodoView({model: todoItem}); 
    this.$el.append(todoView.render().el);

}
```

The addOne function is being called from the render function.  addOne function definition shows that one parameter "todoItem" is being passed to it.  But if you look at the call to addOne from render, it does not show an argument/parameter being passed to it.  How is it possible that the code works correctly?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Bharat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument of the `forEach` function is a callback function, and the `forEach` function calls that function, handing in each element of the array as a parameter.

More visually, your call to `forEach` would lead to:

```
this.collection.forEach(this.addOne, this) -> 
           |this.addOne(this.collection[0], 0, this.collection)
           |this.addOne(this.collection[1], 1, this.collection)
           |this.addOne(this.collection[2], 2, this.collection)
           |this.addOne(this.collection[3], 3, this.collection)
           |this.addOne(this.collection[4], 4, this.collection)
           |...
           |this.addOne(this.collection[n], n, this.collection)
```

.. where `n` represents the last index of the array `this.collection`.

The function `addOne` will ignore the second and third parameters because `addOne` only specified one parameter. Also, `this` from `addOne` will be set to the `this` variable from `render`.

More details are available from the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff679980%28v=vs.94%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks everyone!  I was totally confused between the "underscore" each (aliased to forEach) and the newer Javascript forEach.  the links above are really helpful in clarifying your answer.

Answer (score 0):

`this.render` doesn't directly call `this.addOne`; rather, it calls `this.collection.forEach`, passing in `this.addOne` — the function itself — as an argument. It is `this.collection.forEach` that invokes the function that you pass it.

For a simpler example, this code-snippet:

```
function call_function(f, arg)
{
    f(arg);      // call the function you passed in
}

call_function(alert, s);
```

will do this:

```
alert(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). It's all pretty simple actually. `forEach` calls `addOne` once for each element in the collection and passes it the parameters `(element, index, array)`. In this case, `addOne` simply ignores all but the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

The forEach is implemented in JavaScript 1.6 and if you look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) it is something like this:

```
array.forEach(callback[, thisArg])
```

The second parameter in the forEach part of the render is actually the passed argument to the addOne function which is 'todoItem'. The 'this' refers to the array collection, and the addOne callback will be executed for each item in this collection.